# CSS how to adjust padding according to screen width

Tags: css, forms, symfony

Using Symfony I have a form that I'm rendering and I want its maximum width to be 800px and for the form to be central. If the screen is smaller then it should fill the screen. At the moment I'm using this in my template:

```
{% block body %}
    <div class="main-area">
        {{ form(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

and this in my CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 801px) {
    textarea {width: 801px;}
}


@media (max-width: 800px) {
    textarea {width: 100%;}
}
```

This works fine but aligns everything over on the left and I want the form to be in the centre. So if I add:

```
.main-area {text-align: center;}
```

it aligns everything in the centrally in the form - label, submit button etc.
Then if I add:

```
label { text-align: left;}
```

the label is taken to the far left and no longer aligned with the textarea and the rest of the form.

I think I need to be adjusting the padding around the form, so that if the screen width is less than 800px there is no padding, if it is wider than 800px then the form is rendered at 800px wide with padding on each side. But how to do this in CSS is my question...

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Edit:

Here is the php form type:

```
class InputForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('label1', TextareaType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'text-class')))
        ->add('label2', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('submit form', SubmitType::class);
    }
}
```

and here is the form entity:

```
class Input
{
 ...
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $field1;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $field2;

...
```

Comment: `textarea { max-width: 800px }` should be enough for restricting your textareas width. No need for media queries here. And for the second problem we need to see the rendered HTML.

Comment: It restricts the textarea but doesn't help with aligning the other form elements like labels, submit button etc.

Comment: So please edit your question and show us the rendered HTML from `{{ form(form) }}`, but please not every field ;)

Comment: I think I've done this now but please let me know if this isn't what you were asking for. Many thanks.

Comment: I mean the rendered HTML. For example: `<div><label>foo</label><textarea>...`

Comment: Ah ok, I've not rendered it in that detail, I've slightly edited as above but basically I've just used {{ form(form) }}

Comment: Why don't you just add a class to your form and apply a style to make a clean container with your `max-width 800px` ans juste center this in you page (use flex or `margin: 0 auto`)